# ros-indigo installation libyaml-cpp-dev error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ros, yaml-cpp

I'm new to ROS and Linux and am trying to install Ros indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 trusty following the tutorials:
http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Installation

I keep on having the following issue:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-camera-calibration-parsers : Depends: libyaml-cpp-dev but it is not going to be installed
 ros-indigo-ros : Depends: ros-indigo-mk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ros-indigo-rosbash but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ros-indigo-rosboost-cfg but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ros-indigo-roscreate but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ros-indigo-roslang but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ros-indigo-rosmake but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

whenever I try to fix this with the suggested sudo apt-get -f install, the following happens:

```
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libyaml-cpp-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libyaml-cpp-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/339 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,460 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 370013 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libyaml-cpp-dev_0.5.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libyaml-cpp-dev (0.5.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libyaml-cpp-dev_0.5.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/pkgconfig/yaml-cpp.pc', which is also in package yaml-cpp 0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libyaml-cpp-dev_0.5.1-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried removing ros and yaml-cpp and reinstalling them as some forum-posts suggested, but it didn't seem to work. I also tried to install the libyaml-cpp-dev manualy, but that didn't seem to work either. I'm running out of ideas :/

Greetings,
Rose

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to install ROS Indigo on Precise which is not a supported platform [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html)

Please note the best place to search for ROS issues is http://answers.ros.org as outline at: http://wiki.ros.org/Support